# Javascript JSON IMAGE FROM Webpage

Tags: javascript

How can I add image from "Pexels" webpage to JSON file ? Then I want print it to display .
My output show me URL address of webpage no image.

this is my output in screen:
https://www.pexels.com/photo/person-walking-between-green-forest-trees-15286/

Title1

```
  function getdata() {
  fetch('data.json')
   .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      let out = ''
      data.forEach(function(item){
        out += `
         <div>${item.image}</div>
         <div>${item.title}</div>
        `
      })
      document.querySelector('.output').innerHTML = out
    })
    .catch(function(err){
      console.log(err)
    })
}

getdata()




 My JSON FILE 
[
  {
    "title":"Title1",
    "image": "https://www.pexels.com/photo/person-walking-between-green-forest-trees-15286/"
  }
]

THANKS
```

Comment: Maybe try using this link: https://images.pexels.com/photos/15286/pexels-photo.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=3&h=750&w=1260 Also use iframe and do some DOM. If you don't know what I mean then you can ask me to write a more detailed answer and I will do so.

Comment: If you want to use image use <img /> tag like `<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/15286/pexels-photo.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=2&h=650&w=940">` And from that page use the image url not the full page URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add an image tag with src provided to render the image.

```
  function getdata() {
  fetch('data.json')
   .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      let out = ''
      data.forEach(function(item){
        out += `
         <div><img src="${item.image}" /></div>
         <div>${item.title}</div>
        `
      })
      document.querySelector('.output').innerHTML = out
    })
    .catch(function(err){
      console.log(err)
    })
}
```